# Create loop to change background color in table form Access 2007

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access-2007, conditional-formatting

I created a db in access where an article list is shown with its status in a table subform. there are 5 different status option and I need them to have a specific color. but in access 2007 I can only use 3 conditional formatting statements (4 if you count the default setting).

But I need 5. (01, 05, 06, 08, 09). I've been looking everywhere, but I can't seem to find away around this.

I've been trying from this angle:

```
If Me.txtArtikelStatus = "05" Then
    Me.txtArtikelStatus.BackColor = RGB(215, 228, 188)
ElseIf Me.txtArtikelStatus = "01" Then
    Me.txtArtikelStatus.BackColor = RGB(219, 238, 243)
ElseIf Me.txtArtikelStatus = "06" Then
    Me.txtArtikelStatus.BackColor = RGB(252, 213, 180)
Else
    Me.txtArtikelStatus.BackColor = RGB(230, 182, 184)
End If
```

But that's as far as I got. all records are now the same color (green according to status 05)

My subforms name is `fsubAlleArtikelen`, and it's based on a query called `qryAlleArtikelen` which is based on tables `tblZMMPC` and `tblZMAC`

The column for the status is called `txtArtikelStatus` and is a `text` column.

I'm guessing I need to create a loop, but I don't know enough about VBA to be able to create one that actually works.

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Select case` statement.

This is much cleaner to do a lot of this sort of thing. You can have options which then effectively do a large if/elseif statement like you are trying to do but the code works a lot better (and is cleaner).

See [this link](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php) for more documentation.

Here is what will work for your situation:

```
Select Case Me.txtArtikelStatus

    Case "05"
        Me.txtArtikelStatus.BackColor = RGB(215, 228, 188)

    Case "01"
        Me.txtArtikelStatus.BackColor = RGB(219, 238, 243)

    Case "06"
        Me.txtArtikelStatus.BackColor = RGB(252, 213, 180)

    Case "08"
        Me.txtArtikelStatus.BackColor = RGB(252, 213, 180)
    Case "09"
        Me.txtArtikelStatus.BackColor = RGB(252, 213, 180)

    Case Default
        'this captures everything else

End Select
```

Comment: tried that too, but still all cells are colored the same

Comment: I think the problem might be thet form table view or continuous form view. neither of then give me what I need to see. in excel it's no problem. but with moren than 20000 records, excel becomes slow. that's why I switched to access

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking by your code post that you are trying to do this in a continuous subform. Unfortunately, if you change a property of one control such as the color, it will do it for all visible controls of the same name in the continuous subform. I will try to explain a workaround.

1) Create a separate table that has 2 columns: an ID column which for you will store "05", "01", etc. The next column will be an OLE Object where you can store an image that contains this color.

2) Modify your form's data source to join the column txtArtikelStatus is fed from to the ID column from #1 and add the OLE column to the output.

3) Place a "Bound Object Frame" on your form and make its control source property the OLE column from #2.

If everything is ok then you will now see the status colors.

Answer (score 0):

thqanks guys. I still haven't been able to do what I want. But for the time being I adjusted my expectations and just left one of the statuses out so I could use the conditional formatting.